# summation of XOR of X with each of the array element from range L to R both

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I trying to solve this problem [i demand a trial by combat](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/bit-manipulation/basics-of-bit-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/a-98/) in hackerearth and i mostly solve but i get TLE in testcase after 3
 My solutions take time complexity

> O(Q*R+L-1) which mean O(N^2)
>   Is there any way to solve this problem
>   In O(N) or less time 
>   Here is my solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ll long long 

int main(){

ll q,x,n,r,l;

scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&q);

ll arr[n];

for(ll i=0; i<n; i++){

    scanf("%lld",&arr[i]);
}

while(q--){

    scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&l,&r,&x);

    ll sum = 0;

    for(ll i=l-1; i<r; i++){

        sum += arr[i]^x;
    }

    printf("%lld\n",sum);
}
}
```

Problem:

You are given an array of integers A of size N. Now you are given Q queries to be performed over this array.

In each of the query, you are given 3 space separated integers L, R and X, you need to output the summation of XOR of X with each of the array element from range L to R both inclusive ( 1-based indexing ).

```
sum (i=l to r) of A[i] XOR X     In simple terms
```

Constraints:

1 <= N,Q <= 10^5

1 <= A[i] <= 10^9

1 <= L,R <= N

1 <= X <= 10^9

Answer (score 3):

We can store the frequency of each bit in its own prefix array. For each set bit in X, we have as many ones as there are zero bits in that range. For each unset bit in X, we have as many ones as there are ones in that range.

For example:

```
A = [3, 4]

// Frequency prefixes of each bit
ps[0] = [1, 1]
ps[1] = [1, 1]
ps[2] = [0, 1]

X = 5, L = 1, R = 2

bit 0 is set in X so we add one 1
  (for the unset bit 0 in 4)

bit 1 is unset in X so we add one 1
  (for the set bit 1 in 3)

bit 2 is set in X so we add one 1
  (for the unset bit in 3)

1*1 + 1*2 + 1*4 = 7
```

For each query, we can get the number of ones per bit for a range in O(1) using our bit frequency prefix array. Then we need to sum 30 multiplications. All together 30 * 10^5 queries, which is O(Q).

Comment: I am confused with with `Frequency prefixes of each bit` part. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @JohnKoch it's commonly known as "prefix sums." Looking at just the first bit of each number in [1,2,3,4], we have [1,0,1,0] (first bit is set in 1, unset in 2, etc.). A prefix sum in this case is the same as what I called "frequency prefix": ps = [1,1,2,2]. Say we wanted to know how many 1's are between indexes (2,3). We can calculate that by subtracting ps[3] - ps[1] = 2 - 1 = 1. And just for index (3): ps[3] - ps[2] = 2 - 2 = 0. Makes sense?

Comment: גלעד ברקן@ I see. [1, 1, 2, 2] is the [partial sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Partial_sums) of [1, 0, 1, 0]. Not related to the topic, but it's funny that when I try to @ your name, the @ sign automatically goes to right side. It's the first name I @ a Hebrew name.

Comment: @JohnKoch heh, I didn't know that it flips the alignment. Cool.